# How to make the libcurl send digest authentication header in each http packet?

Tags: c, libcurl

I have the following function `http_send_message()`  wich I use each time I want to send a http message:

```
http_send_message(char *msg_out, char **msg_in)
{
    CURLcode res;
    CURL *curl;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) return -1;

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.133:8080/tawtaw");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "tawtaw");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "tawtaw");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC|CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
        .
        .
        .
   curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
}
```

But I remarked in each time the function send the http message, it try to send a request without the digest authentication header and then it send it with the digest authentication header. In normal case It should do this behaviour only in the first message. And for the subsequent messages it should remeber the authentication header and send it in each message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain such a behavior you need to **re-use you curl handle** for the subsequent calls to take full advantage of persistent connections and [Digest Access Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) request counter:

> [...] the client may make another request, reusing the server nonce value (the server only issues a new nonce for each "401" response) but providing a new client nonce (cnonce). For subsequent requests, the hexadecimal request counter (nc) must be greater than the last value it used

In practice do not clean up your curl handle. Instead maintain it and as soon as you need to perform another request:

- reset it with the [curl_easy_reset](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_reset.html) function: `curl_easy_reset(curl);`
- then re-set your options.

If you use the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option you will see that for the subsequent requests you will have an `Authorization` header with an increasing request counter (`nc=00000002`, `nc=00000003`, etc).

Comment: did not cause a memory leak? the fact of using `curl_easy_reset` and re-set options each time I send http message?

Comment: No. If you refer to the [doc](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) you will see that _[...] if you want subsequent transfers with different options, you must change them between the transfers. You can optionally reset all options back to internal default with curl_easy_reset(3)_. Of course, all you need to do is call `curl_easy_cleanup` when you are done with your handle.

Comment: re-using the same handle is also good for several other reasons like connection re-use and more!

Comment: is this possible in a web context?