# Get cUrl to preemptively send Authorization header for DIGEST authentication in PHP

Tags: php, libcurl, curl-multi, http-digest

We have a PHP page (actually a WordPress plugin) which makes calls to a REST API with DIGEST authentication. The curl handle is created on a per request basis, given authorisation credentials and successfully authenticates.

PROBLEM:

Under the hood, Curl is sending two requests. The first fails with a 401 and a challenge, the second contains an Authorization header and succeeds (200)

Upon subsequent API calls cUrl continues to send two requests. This seems inefficient, causing 2 x network latency to be added to the duration of the operation.

How do we cause cURL to "pre-emptively authenticate" ([example](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html#Preemptive_Authentication)) future requests?

Does Curl Multi have this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You must re-use the same curl handle: see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759452/how-to-make-the-libcurl-send-digest-authentication-header-in-each-http-packet/13760549#13760549) for more details.

As far as the multi interface is concerned you also need to explicitly reuse each handle to leverage the Digest Access Authentication request counter, i.e. with the C API in mind:

1. remove your handle from the multi handle with `curl_multi_remove_handle`
2. reset it with `curl_easy_reset`
3. set the options for the next call
4. re-add it into the multi handle with `curl_multi_add_handle`