# Libcurl with digest authorization in C: send http requests periodically

Tags: c, multithreading, libcurl, alarm, digest

I'm developing a system that tracks objects with a P(an)T(ilt)Z(oom) camera which can be controlled via HTTP requests. The C application I develop is supposed to receive position data of the tracked object and to send commands to the camera to control the pan and tilt angle. In addition to these commands the camera has to receive a session refresh command every 5 seconds. HTTP Digest Authorization has to be used for the connection.

I'm sending the HTTP request with libcurl. I figured already out that for digest auth one needs to use on and the same curl handle for all requests [in this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13760549/2586678).
For sending the session refresh command periodically I tried to use a thread which is just doing this:

```
while(1)
{
    usleep(5000000);
    sessionContinue(g_Config.cam_ip);
}
```

With sessionContinue looking like this:

```
CURLcode sessionContinue(char* url)
{
   CURLcode res;
   char requestURL[40];
   char referer[47];
   struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;

   strcpy(requestURL , url);
   strcat(requestURL, CAM_SESSION_CONTINUE);

   strcpy(referer , "Referer: http://");
   strcat(referer , url);
   strcat(referer , CAM_MONITOR);

   headers = curl_slist_append(headers,"Connection:keep-alive");
   headers = curl_slist_append(headers, camCookie);

   // In windows, this will init the winsock stuff
   curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

   curl_easy_reset(curl);
   if(curl) 
   {
    // First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
    //just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
    //data.

    curl_easy_setopt( curl , CURLOPT_URL        , requestURL                        );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , headers                           );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl , CURLOPT_HTTPGET    , 1                                 );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl , CURLOPT_USERNAME   , "root"                            );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl , CURLOPT_PASSWORD   , "password"                        );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl , CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH   , CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_DIGEST  );

    // Perform the request, res will get the return code
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    // Check for errors
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed @ %s:%d : %s\n",  curl_easy_strerror(res) , __FILE__ , __LINE__ );
    }

return res;
}
```

The application always crashed with segmentation fault after executing `curl_easy_perform(curl)`. So I read the libcurl tutorial again and now I know that  [**using one curl handle in multiple threads is a no go**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html#Multi-threading).

What I tried then was to use a timer with SIGALRM to implement the periodic session refresh. This didn't change the problem with the crash at `curl_easy_perform(curl)`. The strange thing is that the application doesn't crash when sending the normal command to control the pan and tilt position which uses the same curl handle. The only difference between session refresh and pan/tilt command is that session refresh uses GET and pan/tilt uses POST.

**Are there any other possibilities to send pan/tilt commands continuously with a short pause every 5 seconds used to send the session refresh?**

Answer (score 1):

You have a long range of problems in one small program. Here's a few:

1. You might overflow one of those small fixed-size buffers with the dangerous unbounded C functions you use. Quite likely one of them is the reason for the segfault.
2. curl_global_init() is documented to be called *once*, you call it over and over again - this even without calling curl_global_cleanup() in between. You obviously call curl_easy_init() somewhere out of the function and you should move the global init there.
3. 'referer' gets filled with data but is never used otherwise

Another advice is to use CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER to get error messages in rather than curl_easy_strerror() as you may get some extra details then. And of course to set CURLOPT_VERBOSE while debugging the request to see that things look the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment Daniel Stenberg. I'm now calling `curl_global_init()` just once when the handle has been set up. `referer` wasn't really needed here, but I had forgotten to remove it before pasting the code here.

The reason for the segmentation fault was that the session refresh command and the commands for pan and tilt tried to use one and the same curl handle at the same time, which obviously can't really work. So the solution with the timer and SIGALRM wasn't the problem. The segmentation faults have been solved by adding a mutex lock to avoid concurrent accesses to the curl handle.